# Cannot subscript a value of type 'inout [MenuItem]' (aka 'inout Array<MenuItem>')

Tags: ios, swift

I have this weird error message in my TableViewController class

```
class MenuTableViewController: UITableViewController {
fileprivate var menuItems = [MenuItem]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "MenuItemTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: CELL_MENU_ITEM)
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return menuItems.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: CELL_MENU_ITEM, for: indexPath) as! MenuItemTableViewCell

    // this line throws the error message
    if let menuItem = self.menuItems[indexPath.row].getTitle() as [MenuItem] {
        cell.itemTitleLabel.text = menuItem
    }


    return cell
}

func setMenuItems(menuItems: [MenuItem]) {
    self.menuItems = menuItems
}    
}
```

I totally don't know what that error means. There are others facing this problem with type inout but they are doing errors with '=' instead of '==' and things like that. By the way the value of menuItems get set in another class in a completion function. But if I remove it from there I still got this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `menuItems` is declared as a concrete **non-optional** type there is no type casting nor optional binding needed.

```
let menuItem = self.menuItems[indexPath.row]
cell.itemTitleLabel.text = menuItem.getTitle()
```

The error message might be misleading. You are trying to cast (presumed) `String` to `[MenuItem]`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want to check `MenuItem`? like that:

```
if let menuItem = self.menuItems[indexPath.row] as MenuItem {
    cell.itemTitleLabel.text = menuItem.getTitle()
}
```

And you declare your collection with `[MenuItem]` type, so subscription will return non-optional value, you can remove `iflet` check and use:

`cell.itemTitleLabel.text = self.menuItems[indexPath.row].getTitle()`

Comment: Thanks, I had it like that before but it was not working. In the way vadian is implementing it, it works. Maybe an error in Xcode because I think your/my version and his are the same. Anyway thank you very much!

Comment: @Brudus It's not the same and there is no error in Xcode. The compiler does not allow optional binding (`if let`) applied to a non-optional type.

Comment: Yeah I know what you mean, but I just added that if let because of another error. I think it was an error in Xcode but after revisiting it, it could also be another error from mine.

Answer (score 0):

I have missed to import uikit in my custom struct and get a similar error. hope it helps somebody reading here.